# Django. Форма не проходит валидацию

Tags: django

Выдает ошибку:

```
error:
  type: 0 "Обязательное поле."
  name: 0 "Обязательное поле."
```

Форма:

```
<form action="/send_resume" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="snp" placeholder="ФИО">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
  <input type="file" name="attach_file" accept=".pdf" required>

  <button>Отправить резюме</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def send_resume(request):
    form = ResumeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        send_mail('mail/resume.html', {
            'resume': form.cleaned_data
        })
        return JsonResponse({'result' : 'ok'})
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return JsonResponse({'error' : form.errors})
```

forms.py

```
class ResumeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Resume
        fields = "__all__"
```

models.py

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ("sp", "Специалистам"),
        ("st", "Студентам"),
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default="sp", verbose_name="Тип")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="ФИО")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Email")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=PathRename("resume"), verbose_name="Файл", blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, null=True, verbose_name="Дата")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Резюме"
        verbose_name_plural = "6. Резюме"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ну, из модели очевидно, что поля `type` и `name` и в самом деле нигде не заполнены. В чём тогда вопрос-то?